# How to add a hook in Wordpress Super Form Plugin to store Form in Wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, hook

I am facing a problem in hooking the form to wordpress database. Currently all fields are showing in Wordpress Contact Entries using WP Super Forms but not been able to store in database using phpmyadmin.
[Contact Entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsN25.jpg)

Please tell me how to store Form fields it in database using Hooks:

List of available hooks are:

**Actions:**

super-forms\includes\class-ajax.php:

```
super_before_load_form_dropdown_hook 
super_after_load_form_dropdown_hook
```

super-forms\includes\class-ajax.php:

```
super_before_sending_email_hook 
super_before_email_success_msg_action
super_after_saving_contact_entry_action
```

Thank you.

Comment: from your screenshot i can see data saved to the db? what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: The data is showing in the wordpress plugin contact entries menuitem but when I see database there are not any form fields. Its the JSON file but I want to store form fields in the database using the plugin WP SuperForms.

Comment: what json?the plugin should use a custom post type, and the fields should be saved in the meta post table

Comment: I have seen it the meta post table there is not any fields that is storing the form data. Apart from that in the table: wp_post I have seen the value of my form [super_form id="4"] in the column post_content. Apart from that there is no value in the database for this form. Only I can see contact entries on the wordpress backend.